# Unable to update group policy(local gpo) status to "Not Configured" using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

With PowerShell, by updating corresponding registry keys we can able to toggle the local GPO status to "Enabled" or "Disabled", but I have a specific requirement to make sure that certain local GPOs are set to "Not configured". Tried deleting corresponding registry keys but it didn't help.

Is there any way to achieve this in PowerShell?

Comment: What keys are you deleting and for which policy?

Comment: Removable Disks: Deny write access , i want to restore this local gpo state to ''Not Configured"

Comment: with Powershell i tride deleting following hive HKML:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\windows\RemovableStorageDevices .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run `Local Group Policy Editor` (`gpedit.msc`) as `Administrator` and set the `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access\Removable Disks: Deny write access` policy to `Enabled` or `Disabled`, according to [`Process Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) that is actually setting the `Deny_Write` value at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{GUIDGUID-GUID-GUID-GUID-GUIDGUIDGUID}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`.

If I modify, delete, or rename that `Deny_Write` value as `Administrator` then I see the change reflected in `Local Group Policy Editor` when I edit/reopen that policy.  I'm not exactly certain how it is that a machine policy is being set under a user's registry; perhaps there's a symbolic link or loaded hive at play.  `Process Monitor` indicates that `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol` is also modified at the time I set the policy, so that must be the underlying storage for `Group Policy`-based registry changes.

Comment: i wanted to change this at system level , By toggling values in HKLM:\Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b} , am able to set the state to enable & Disable . Tried deleting this registry which is not setting the gpo state to "Not Configure" and that  is my desired endstate

Comment: I understand that.  What my answer is saying is that `Local Group Policy Editor` is manipulating the `RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}` key under (what appears to be) HKCU, not HKLM, because it is backed by the machine-specific `Registry.pol`, so that's the key you should try deleting.  See [Why gpedit and the corresponding registry entries are not synchronized?](https://superuser.com/q/1192405/34985).  In other words, the key you're deleting contains the current system setting, whereas the key I'm referencing contains the _policy_ setting.

Comment: it worked :) , but i have observed that when i switch user gpo state is changed again

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.  I'm not altogether certain what the relationship/mechanism is between the user registry key and the machine policy file.  I was thinking maybe it just gets loaded under HKCU because there's nowhere else to link it, but evidently not.